# Reading from a YAML file in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to read a YAML file in Kotlin.

In short, the YAML has the following format:

```yaml
aws:
  foo:
    dev:
      id: '1111'
    pro:
      id: '2222'
  bar:
    dev:
      id: '3333'
    pro:
      id: '4444'
```

I have created these data classes:

```kotlin
data class Account (
        val id: String
)

data class Owner (
        val accounts: List<Account>
)

data class Cloud (
        val owners: List<Owner>
)
```

And then I try to parse the file with:

```kotlin
val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
val settings: Cloud = mapper.readValue(Path.of("accounts.yaml").toFile())
# also tried this
val settings: List<Cloud> = mapper.readValue(Path.of("accounts.yaml").toFile())
println(settings)
```

the `println` fails with `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'aws': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')`

Why?

Comment: YAML and JSON are not the same

Comment: @IvoBeckers of course they are not. Just fixed the `val mapper` line which was not correct in the text of the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include the `jackson-dataformat-yaml` dependency and then create your ObjectMapper like this:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

Comment: Since kotlin 2.12.4 the above KotlinModule constructor is deprecated, so instead use `ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerKotlinModule()`

Answer (score 8):

An alternative would be to use [Kaml](https://github.com/charleskorn/kaml):

Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
implementation("com.charleskorn.kaml:kaml:0.46.0")
```

Then add @Serializable annotation to your data classes:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Cloud (
    val owners: List<Owner>
)
```

Then you can parse it from YAML:

```kotlin
val parsedYaml = Yaml.default.decodeFromString(Cloud.serializer(), Path.of("accounts.yaml").toFile().readText())
```

Answer (score 3):

Add dependencies:

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.15.2")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.15.2")
```

Create mapper:

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerKotlinModule()
```